# Get NPSP account model using Apex or SOQL

Tags: apex, soql, npsp

Good day everyone,

Does anyone here know how to check the account model in NPSP. I want to know if account model is household model, one-to-one or etc. I'm trying to search in the net but no luck. Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find it with this:

SELECT npe01__Account_Processor__c FROM npe01__Contacts_And_Orgs_Settings__c